# on how many supercomputers does Ubuntu actually run on

Tags: 12.04

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/495321/on-how-many-supercomputers-does-linux-actually-run-on) on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) on how many supercomputer run on Linux
and was wondering on how many supercomputer's Ubuntu run on?

Comment: Not sure this question can be answered with conclusive facts, making it sort of not right for the site. Not sure if there are actual ratings that one can have a look at for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the operating system breakdown, amongst other statistics for the top 500 supercomputers [here](http://i.top500.org/stats).

About 90% use some variety of Linux. None report using Ubuntu, but almost none specify exactly which Linux distribution they use.

I suspect the majority use their own customised distributions  with both the kernel and software tailored for their hardware and major uses. My guess would be that they would use either Red Hat or Debian (as Ubuntu does) as a starting point for customisation, but this is just my supposition.

Answer (score 0):

Your other question asks how many supercomputers run Linux. You may be confused between Ubuntu and Linux here.

An OS used on a supercomputer is likely to be customised one way or another, although it can be based on a specific distribution. I'm not aware of any that's based on Ubuntu.

As [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/495324/42341) said, check the [Top 500](http://i.top500.org/stats) stats, by "Operating System" and "Operating System Family".

It's hard to assess from the general "Linux" category what it's running. Generally speaking Ubuntu is targeted to be more user-friendly, it's not really aimed for this more specialised market.